# Maximizing the given function.

Tags: functions, maxima-minima

How would I maximize the function,

$$ f(x,y,z) = \min(x,y) + z $$

Given the constraint that,
$$x+y+z=1$$

Edit: Additional constraint:

$$x,y,z \geq 0$$

Comment: I think that the problem is unbounded. It seems that additional constraints are missing.

Comment: Note that $f(x,y,z)=1-\max(x,y),$ since $\max(x,y)+\min(x,y)=x+y.$

Comment: Added the additional constraint.

Comment: With non-negative $x,y,z,$ $f(x,y,z)=1-\max(x,y)\leq 1.$ But we have $f(0,0,1)=1.$ So $1$ is the maximum value.